# Providing an alternative to equals()?

Tags: java

Let's say I have a class called `Number`, and I intend to do a lot of equality comparisons of `Number` objects. I am concerned about the "overhead" (class comparison, etc...) of the generic `Number::equals(Object o)` method. In this case, is it useful to provide a method such as `Number::isEqualTo(Number other)` as an alternative to `Number::equals(Object o)`? Is this a common pattern? Or do JVMs currently optimize well enough that there is no advantage to doing this?

Here's a code example:

```
public class Number {
    int _value;

    Number(int value) {
        _value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if (o == this) return true;
        if (o == null) return false;
        if (o.getClass() != getClass()) return false;
        return isEqualTo((Number)o);
    }

    public boolean isEqualTo(final Number other) {
        return _value == other._value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Number one = new Number(1);
        Number two = new Number(2);
        if (!one.isEqualTo(two)) {
            System.out.println("fast comparison?");
        }
        if (!one.equals(two)) {
            System.out.println("slow comparison?");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you isEqualTo method is just going to do `==` anyways, just use `==` instead of a method.

Comment: If you're worried about performance, measure it.

Comment: You could measure the performance difference of both methods, shouldn't be hard

Comment: Also, don't call your class `Number`, that name's taken already.

Comment: Just remember that by doing that, you're providing an equality check that might be inconsistent with the `equals` check, that's widely used by default in Java. This can lead to contradictions and hard-to-detect bugs. Make sure that both methods return consistent results.

Comment: You're chasing nano-seconds.  Don't make a confusing API like that unless you've proven the difference is meaningful for your application.  (and if it is, it's probably not something that should have been written in java in the first place.. :) )

Comment: @A.R.S. Sorry, new to Java. I should have checked before calling my test class `Number`. @Gamb - sounds like good advice. @Affe Repeated nano-second overhead could actually be an issue in my application. The choice of language isn't mine to make in this case :) But from the responses I've seen, it seems that this type of optimization may not be prudent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may even provide an overload of `equals` itself: `equals(Number)`. If you implement it **very carefully** (to be behaviorally indistinguishable from `equals(Object)`), you can achieve a minuscule speedup by avoiding a checked downcast in certain cases. Note that you are still going to have to check `a.getClass() == b.getClass()` so the difference is vanishingly small.

Comment: If I make `Number` a `final` class (reasonable for my case, which isn't actually a simple "number") can I avoid the getClass() comparison?

Comment: Yes, then you'd have it guaranteed that any `o instanceof Number` has `o.getClass() == Number.class`.

Answer (score 5):

The two methods have different semantic:

- `equals` has the semantic dictated by the `Object::equals` contract, while
- `isEqualTo` has the semantic that applies exclusively to `Number` objects

Since the comparison is not apples-to-apples, it is fair that `equals` would require more CPU cycles. It is unlikely that you would notice the difference, however.

It is far more common for classes like yours to implement [`Comparable<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). The semantic there calls for an ordering check, not just for an equality checks, but there is no requirement to take objects of unknown classes, letting you save CPU cycles.

You should have a good reason to provide an alternative to equality (e.g. a profiler run that points to `equals(Object)` as a bottleneck, a perceived improvement on readability due to the change, or achieving richer semantic due to adopting an interface that does more). Doing it for the sake of cutting a few CPU cycles would premature optimization.

Comment: Yep.  (I would also totally expect JVMs to optimize almost all the overhead of the class comparison away.)

Answer (score 3):

A quick microbenchmark with the most unfavourable scenario (`equals` always calls `isEqualTo`) shows (in ms):

> equals: 1014
>   isEqualTo: 1010

Bottom line: unless your program doesn't do anything else, this is not going to be a performance bottleneck and you should stick to the first principle of optimisation: profile first, then optimise what needs to be optimised.

Test code:

```
public class TestPerf {

    private static int NUM_RUN;
    private static List<Number> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NUM_RUN = 100_000;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            list.add(new Number(i));
        }

        long sum = 0;
        System.out.println("Warmup");

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RUN; i++) {
            sum += method1(17);
            sum += method2(17);
        }

        System.gc();

        System.out.println("Starting");

        sum = 0;
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RUN; i++) {
            sum += method1(17);
        }
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("equals: " + (end - start) / 1000000);

        System.gc();

        start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RUN; i++) {
            sum += method2(17);
        }
        end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("isEqualTo: " + (end - start) / 1000000);

        System.out.println(sum);
    }

    private static int method1(int target) {
        int sum = 0;
        Number comparison = new Number(target);
        for (Number n : list) {
            if (n.equals(comparison)) sum++;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    private static int method2(int target) {
        int sum = 0;
        Number comparison = new Number(target);
        for (Number n : list) {
            if (n.isEqualTo(comparison)) sum++;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static class Number {

        int _value;

        Number(int value) {
            _value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(final Object o) {
            if (o == this) return true;
            if (o == null) return false;
            if (o.getClass() != getClass()) return false;
            return isEqualTo((Number) o);
        }

        public boolean isEqualTo(final Number other) {
            return _value == other._value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this might be dominated by list iteration logic. Maybe use an array instead? It could show a bit more difference.

Comment: I think that the point is that this is an O(1) algorithm no matter what you do, so optimization is unlikely to yield any significant advantage.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Fair point - and actually depending on which runs first the results vary slightly.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik With an array, the results are close too, around 600ms (with a variation of +/- 5ms across multiple runs).

Comment: Yes, they can't get far apart no matter what, I'd expect only a minor increase in the difference.

Comment: @BaileyS If an O(1) algo is used in each step of an O(n) algo, and is the dominant factor in it, then it does make a difference.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik  Actually having an O(1) algorithm nested in an O(n) algorithm results in... O(n) run time.  Sure, a few clock cycles in a loop matter... nobody here is disagreeing.  The problem is that type of optimization belongs much later in the development process during code profiling.  During development clarity is king, and a developer is well advised to focus on the big O(n) picture.

Comment: @BaileyS If, under the terms I have defined, we speed up the O(1) algo by a factor of ten, how much speedup will the O(n) algo receive? Moreover, the same logic applies to O(n^2) and any other complexity.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik In big O notation, none.  That is the point of big O notation, to help computer scientists ignore inane optimizations.  Shaving off a few lines of code rarely results in any benefit, particularly with an optimizing compiler.

Comment: @BaileyS So even if my program runs **ten times slower**, I should still helplessly throw my hands into the air, whispering "I'm doomed! All my time is spent in an O(1) algorithm and you **just can't improve an O(1) algorithm**"?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik You should finish your program, profile it, determine empirically what part is actually running slowly, and explore constant factor optimizations in that code only.  If you can get an O(1) section running 10x faster, all the power to you; although having that problem in the first place would qualify as being a ***horrible programmer***.  In the case of the actual question we are responding to, the speed increase would be closer to 10%, not 1000%.

Comment: @BaileyS Excuse me, I was under the impression that your argument was about theoretical big-O complexity, whereas **my** argument was about practical concerns. Now you complain that it is me who is approaching this too theoretically? Do you have any point to make at all?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19839/discussion-between-bailey-s-and-marko-topolnik)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on where you'd like to use a compare method.

Maybe you can use different implementations of a Comparator interface?

These can be used to eg. sort Lists.

Answer (score 0):

`xx.isEqualTo.yy` is an comparison on "object" level. It simply checks whether this two object are referring the same object.

It is always better to write 'equations methods' for specific classes. For example in this case  optimal comparison is simply `==`.